# How to extract all the sentences with review/text in the below text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Here I want to extract the review/text.But its extracting only few parts from it.
Following are the outputs:-
<re.Match object; span=(226, 258), match='review/text: I like Creme Brulee'>
<re.Match object; span=(750, 860), match='review/text: not what I was expecting in terms of>

import re

```
text='''
'product/productId: B004K2IHUO\n',
 'review/userId: A2O9G2521O626G\n',
 'review/profileName: Rachel Westendorf\n',
 'review/helpfulness: 0/0\n',
 'review/score: 5.0\n',
 'review/time: 1308700800\n',
 'review/summary: The best\n',
 'review/text: I like Creme Brulee. I loved that these were so easy. Just sprinkle on the sugar that came with and broil. They look amazing and taste great. My guess thought I really went out of the way for them when really it took all of 5 minutes. I will be ordering more!\n',
 '\n',
 'product/productId: B004K2IHUO\n',
 'review/userId: A1ZKFQLHFZAEH9\n',
 'review/profileName: S. J. Monson "world citizen"\n',
 'review/helpfulness: 2/8\n',
 'review/score: 3.0\n',
 'review/time: 1236384000\n',
 'review/summary: disappointing\n',
 "review/text: not what I was expecting in terms of the company's reputation for excellent home delivery products\n",
 '\n',
'''

pattern=re.compile(r'review/text:\s[^.]+')
matches=pattern.finditer(text)

for match in matches:
  print(match)
```

Comment: Did you want to extract everything up to the newline? Then change the dot to a newline in the negated character set.

Comment: `review/text:\s.+` should work

Comment: Why do you have strings inside strings? It looks like those triple quotes should just be parentheses.

Comment: @AlexHall In that case, `finditer` won't work. But I agree there's something off with the text.

Comment: You can do it without `re`. You need to parse the string as a list, use `import ast` and then `matches = [s for s in ast.literal_eval(f'[{text.replace(chr(10),"")}]') if s.startswith("review/text:")]`. See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/UpdUoM).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind not using `re` and if the identifier is `'review/text'` and your data is always comma seperated, you can get the lines simply with:

```py
matches = [s.strip() for s in text.split(',') if s.strip(' "\n\'').startswith('review/text')]
for match in matches:
  print(match)
```

where `s.strip(' "\'\n')` removes spaces, `"`, `'`, and newline characters from the beginning and ends of the line for a string comparison.These two lines are returned:

```
'review/text: I like Creme Brulee. I loved that these were so easy. Just sprinkle on the sugar that came with and broil. They look amazing and taste great. My guess thought I really went out of the way for them when really it took all of 5 minutes. I will be ordering more!
'
"review/text: not what I was expecting in terms of the company's reputation for excellent home delivery products
"
```

Comment: I doubt OP's actual data looks like that, I think they pprinted the result of `file.readlines()` or something and then stuck that inside triple quotes without understanding what they were doing.

Comment: It does look like a rather strange text input, that's for sure (with the mixed quotes)! But in case they have no control of the input, I thought I'd add a non-`re` solution.

Comment: @Tim Jim Thanks for the answer.I appreciate your effort but is there any way to extract it using regular expressions?

Comment: Just made the following changes and it worked:-pattern=re.compile(r'review/text:\s[^\n]+')
matches=pattern.findall(text)

Comment: @VikasKumarOjha This is exactly what [anubhava suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67555515/how-to-extract-all-the-sentences-with-review-text-in-the-below-text#comment119406396_67555515), `matches = re.findall(r'review/text:\s.+', text)`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```py
matches = re.findall(r'review/text:.+', text)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/5dV05r/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  review/text:             'review/text:'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .+                       any character except \n (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```